# Python | Combine multiple csv (100+) files from one folder taking csv header into consideration

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Requirement: I have a folder with multiple csv files. I need to perform following:

1. Scan the input folder for all csv files (file1.csv, file2.csv ..... filen.csv etc) & perform below steps
2. Open the first csv file (file1.csv) & store the file header in a list & then copy the entire content (including header) of file1.csv & put in combined.csv => Then move file1.csv to a /done folder under the parent folder
3. Move to next file file2.csv => Compare the header of file2.csv with the header of the first file to ensure they match exactly. If the headers match then copy contents (excluding header) of file2.csv & put in combined.csv => Then move file2.csv to a /done folder under the parent folder. If the header of file2.csv do not match then exclude combining this file, leave it in the same parent folder & move to next file for combining

I have placed sample files on the link [gdrive folder with sample CSV files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_1jgRS2IrnHJ_ogHYyVuRzgEnmpuQave)
I am open to any solution either with CSV or pandas as long as it does what I want

As a starting point, I was initially working on comparing the header as below which works. However, I am unsure on how to move further

Code:

```
    import csv        
    def compare_two_csv_headers(csv_file1, csv_file2):
        with open(csv_file1, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            frow1 = next(reader)  # gets the first line
            print(frow1)
        with open(csv_file2, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            frow2 = next(reader)  # gets the first line
            print(frow2)
        if frow1==frow2:
            print('Same header')
        else:
            print('Different header')

    csv_file1 = 'D:/2009/cm01JAN2009bhav.csv'
    csv_file2 = 'D:/2009/cm01DEC2009bhav.csv'
    compare_two_csv_headers(csv_file1, csv_file2)
```

Here are the top 10 lines from the first csv file

```
SYMBOL,SERIES,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,LAST,PREVCLOSE,TOTTRDQTY,TOTTRDVAL,TIMESTAMP,
20MICRONS,EQ,46.5,47,45.7,46.05,46,46.55,7092,328975.25,31-DEC-2009,
3IINFOTECH,EQ,85.8,86.7,84.5,85.15,85.35,85.05,2423812,207760480.3,31-DEC-2009,
3MINDIA,EQ,1855.05,1879.9,1855.05,1865.75,1874.95,1850.45,85,158679.1,31-DEC-2009,
AARTIDRUGS,EQ,107.4,108.75,103.65,104.45,104.9,106.05,84012,8929759.4,31-DEC-2009,
AARTIIND,EQ,51,51.9,48.9,49.2,49.1,50.45,149365,7517110.3,31-DEC-2009,
AARVEEDEN,EQ,64,64.5,63.05,63.85,63.1,62.7,2172,138651.5,31-DEC-2009,
ABAN,EQ,1265,1297,1265,1283.65,1283.2,1260.05,1381290,1773221519.75,31-DEC-2009,
ABB,EQ,756.2,770.85,756.2,767.1,769.55,756.3,292376,223660807.4,31-DEC-2009,
ABCIL,EQ,85.4,89,84.9,86.85,86.95,84.7,59183,5170993.2,31-DEC-2009,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `pandas` methods to iteratively check columns and run import instead of scanning first lines with `csv`. Also, use `os` to manage the file names extract and locations with `shutil` for moving *done* files. Below builds a list of dataframes for final concatenation outside loop.

```
import os, shutil
import pandas as pd

def import_csvs(csv_file):

    path = r'/path/to/csv/files'
    csv_files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(path) if f[-3:] == 'csv'])

    # INITIALIZE DATAFRAME LIST
    df_list = []
    # READ FIRST DF (ASSUMED FIRST IN ALPHABETICAL ORDER)
    first_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, csv_files[0]))
    # APPEND FIRST DF   
    df_list.append(first_df)

    # MOVE FIRST CSV
    shutil.move(os.path.join(path, csv_files[0]), os.path.join(path,'done',csv_files[0]))

    # LOOP ALL OTHER CSVs SKIPPING FIRST
    for f in csv_files[1:]:                 
       # IMPORT CSV
       tmp = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, f))

       # CHECK DF COLUMNS EXACTLY MATCH
       if list(tmp.columns) == list(first_df.columns):  
          # APPEND DF TO LIST
          df_list.append(tmp)

          # MOVE COMPLETED FILE
          shutil.move(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(path, 'done', f))

    final_df = pd.concat(df_list)

    return final_df
```

Comment: Worked exactly as requirement.  After exporting the final_df to a out.csv I see the header of last column says Unnamed: 11. Here are the coulmns in the file: SYMBOL SERIES OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE LAST PREVCLOSE TOTTRDQTY TOTTRDVAL TIMESTAMP Unnamed: 11

Comment: Check your data. Do you have unnamed column 11 in first csv file?

Comment: I don't see any unnamed column in the data. I have uploaded the final out.csv as a zip file on the grdive folder in case you want to take a look at it https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_1jgRS2IrnHJ_ogHYyVuRzgEnmpuQave

Comment: It seems unnamed:11 is the number of header that are there in the files. I opened up all 237 files manually & verified there is no other col. I also ran the code with smaller number of files 1) with 1 file & 2) with 4 files. Every time the out.csv had the unnamed:11 even with random files.

Comment: I am using following to export out.csv <<<< --- final_df.to_csv(dir_path + 'out.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False) --->>>>

Comment: Please open first or any CSV in a text editor (Notepad, TextEdit, gedit, etc.) and check if last column has blanks: `data,data,,` or `data,data,"",`. If so, check how CSVs were originally created. These render as ghost columns in Excel, Lotus, or LibreOffice which cannot be seen without content. See where CTRL (CMD in MacOS) + END takes cursor at end of content.

Comment: Tried, but could not find anything. Opened multiple CSV in Notepad++ & searched for following: ,, or ,<space>, or ,"", or ,"<space>", . The CSV are downloaded from an external website & are generated automatically by the server. I do not have a control over the CSV generation. Also, irrespective of the sample CSV file, (I have almost 2000+) the unnamed:11 remains the same. All files have 11 column. So my guess is that the unnamed:11 is not due to some spurious hidden data but rather has something to do with how Pandas sees the 11 Column headers maybe?

Comment: Can you post the first ten rows of **first** csv in the body of your post from Notepad++? You can then format the content with code formatting, `{}`. I cannot access GDrive links from here.

Comment: Added top 10 lines of first csv in my post

Comment: You do have blank columns at end since each line breaks on a comma. Add a line for first csv and in loop to delete it. Ses pandas's [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).